# VBA check changes in a particular cell range

Tags: vba, excel

I need a function that checks if a particular range of cells in vba was changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A9:J100")) Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox Target.Address
   End If
End Sub
```

This code works, the problem is: they changed to the same values (throw an internet update). How to check if the updated cell values really changed to new ones? (without checking one by one ofc)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: You will have to store their content elsewhere and them compare...

Comment: I'm not asking for code, i know how to code (i parcially did it) to resolve de described problem, the question is about funcionalities of the VBA Excel Events. Instead of hard coding something that maybe it is already solved by the tool. I attempt a solution (as can be read in the code) and saw the solution that dnt satisfy my propose.. i really dont understand this critic but ok

Comment: The critic is about having a minimal VBA/programming knowledge (or thinking about the problem twice before asking): your code checks for certain value in certain location and you are asking why it cannot understand that the given value is repeated. The answer is simple: because you haven't instructed it to do so. You would have to set a new condition making sure that this value is not equal to a previous one. And you would have to store this old value somewhere (as proposed by LS_dev). Think about all this and you will understand why this is not the place to ask what you have asked.

Comment: Sorry for my knowledge @varocarbas. I'm not so good as you. One by one check would be my last option as obvious. The question was about other options available by the tool, once i'm not familiarized with the this, shortcuts/events/suggestions instead of checking "by hand" 10.000.000 cells. If there isn't other option just ok - sorry for the question - thanks for the answer.

Comment: Why you feel sorry for you knowledge? Just accept it: if you want to improve it, do it; if you don't want/cannot improve it, accept the consequences (people telling just in SO, a site for programmers with certain knowledge, that you don't meet the minimum requirements). Perhaps you should do a small effort to understand what people is saying you here instead of keeping doing things worse (to support your position): blindfolded, you have 3 objects in front of you; you pick one and put it back together with the other objects; in your second try you might pick up the same one...

Comment: ... how can you make completely sure that you will not pick the same one in subsequent picks? Either by not putting it back where all the objects are or by removing the fold from your eyes and making sure that you don't pick it. Is there any option to accomplish this aim withot performing any of these actions? Evidently, no. But you are asking us if you have a third option by doing basically this. Don't you think that we can safely assume that you don't have the minimum knowledge about the given situation? 3 or 3 millions is the same, there is only one (actually 2) way through.

Comment: PS: you are welcome. I have only clarified a point you didn't seem to have too clear. If now your knowledge is clearer on this point, you should understand that you need either to rephrase your question ("best way to store a high number of values globally...") in a way you prove that you need the kind of help delivered here (how to use VBA, not how to face a very-basic programming problem) and that you fulfil the expected conditions (minimum programming knowledge). Also you can delete this question. Or you can ignore our suggestions and continue doing whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry if my knowledge is too low for you and I accepted it. i said thanks you and to LS_Dev i just dont understand why i have to had such a level of "programmation knowledge"/requirements to post a question.. when i needed only a simple answer (how LS_dev did) And i posted to improve my knowledge. if not i woundn't not ask such a offenssive "bad and dummy question" @varocarbas.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38323/discussion-between-orange-and-varocarbas)

Comment: Because this is a site for programmers. If you don't like the rules, go to meta (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and propose changes; but I don't think that your request will suceed. There are other sites whose rules might be different. You can accept the rules or not, but I don't see the point of getting offended or taking it personally. You keep saying "sorry if my knowledge..." and I (and presumably anyone else here) don't care about your knowledge. I am just helping you to understand that you are not using this site as expected nothing else.

Comment: Now the problem is the use that i gave to the website.. i didnt know if there was a better way to do it, so i posted it - just that. If i put it in the wrong website - maybe, sorry for the inconvenient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this small example, we maintain the memory of the block of data and can thus test if any value has actually changed.  Note the memory has been Dim'ed above the sub to make it static:

```
Dim MemoryOfThingsPast() As Variant
Dim init As Long
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Interesting As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Set Interesting = Range("A9:J100")
    If init = 0 Then
        MemoryOfThingsPast = Interesting
        init = 1
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Intersect(Target, Interesting) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    K = 1
    For I = LBound(MemoryOfThingsPast, 1) To UBound(MemoryOfThingsPast, 1)
        For J = LBound(MemoryOfThingsPast, 2) To UBound(MemoryOfThingsPast, 2)
            v1 = Interesting(K)
            v2 = MemoryOfThingsPast(I, J)
            If v1 <> v2 Then
                MsgBox "Cell " & Interesting(K).Address & " has really changed"
            End If
            K = K + 1
        Next J
    Next I
    MemoryOfThingsPast = Interesting
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the only thing I changed was if v1 <> v2 or init = 0 then init = 1.  Works pretty well for my uses, thanks.

Comment: @JakeGaston  You are quite welcome!