# Loop does not initialize until after first selection is made

Tags: excel, vba

Using this [very helpful example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088467/vba-check-changes-in-a-particular-cell-range) as a starting point (thank you Gary's Student!), I am having trouble initializing the code so it recognizes the very first change. There's a big pile of hair on the table next to me as I've been trying to solve this for 2 days now.....

Basically, I have a range (`B1:B200`) in a table. Through data validation (drop down list), users have a choice of two values for the cells in this range. When they choose a value, I want to pick up that the cell has changed (let's say `B12`) and, based on the new value (either choice 1 or choice 2), the first cell in that row (cell `A12`) has it's value set to one of two different counters.

When the workbook is first opened and a user makes a selection in that range, it doesn't "see" that first change, but each subsequent change is recorded and the value in cell `A` is set properly and the appropriate counter is then incremented.

**One other constraint:** 
If a user chooses a value and cell A is set, they cannot subsequently change the B value from 1 to 2 (otherwise the counters would just keep incrementing).

Does this make sense?

Here's the code I'm working with. Thanks all, very much, for any assistance you can provide:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Interesting As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, INTL As Long, DOMESTIC As Long

    ' These are the values for the two counters, stored in another sheet in
    ' the book:
    INTL = Worksheets("MASTER").Range("A8")
    DOMESTIC = Worksheets("MASTER").Range("A5")

    K = 1
    Set Interesting = Range("B1:B200")
    If init = 0 Then
        MemoryOfThingsPast = Interesting
        init = 1
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Intersect(Target, Interesting) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    K = 1
    ' MsgBox "2. init: " & init & "  v1: " & v1 & "  v2: " & v2

    For I = LBound(MemoryOfThingsPast, 1) To UBound(MemoryOfThingsPast, 1)
        For J = LBound(MemoryOfThingsPast, 2) To UBound(MemoryOfThingsPast, 2)
            ' MsgBox "3. init: " & init & "  v1: " & v1 & "  v2: " & v2

            v1 = Interesting(K)
            v2 = MemoryOfThingsPast(I, J)

            If v1 <> v2 Then
                If Not IsEmpty(Cells(K, 1)) Then
                    If v1 = "INTERNATIONAL" And Left(Cells(K, 1), 1) = "D" Then
                        MsgBox "DOMESTIC counter is already set"
                    ElseIf v1 = "DOMESTIC" And Left(Cells(K, 1), 1) = "I" Then
                        MsgBox "INTERNATIONAL counter is already set"
                    End If
                Else
                    If v1 = "INTERNATIONAL" And IsEmpty(Cells(K, 1)) Then
                        Worksheets("MASTER").Range("A8") = INTL + 1
                        Cells(K, 1) = "I-" & INTL
                        MsgBox "INTL Counter has been set."
                    ElseIf v1 = "DOMESTIC" And IsEmpty(Cells(K, 1)) Then
                        Worksheets("MASTER").Range("A5") = DOMESTIC + 1
                        Cells(K, 1) = "D-" & DOMESTIC
                        MsgBox "DOMESTIC Counter has been set."
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            K = K + 1
        Next J
    Next I

    MemoryOfThingsPast = Interesting
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple `Exit Sub`'s near the beginning that could be causing the issue. I suspect it's the first one and that `init = 0` the first time it is run.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, both Exit Subs are in the original code. I'll try deleting to see if that does the trick. I did find a workaround after posting yesterday, and it works pretty well: I put code in that runs when the workbook is open to write the word "REPORT" in cell B1. This occurs every time the book is opened and runs once. Since its at the top of the page and outside my table, it doesn't interfere with the data. It is effectively the first change to the array (Range(B:B)). After that, the "first" change (really the second!) is picked up and the counters are properly set.

Comment: @shred21 If you answered your own question, please add it as an answer and accept it. That way, future users will easily know which method worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer a day after posting, and it works pretty well:

I put code in that runs when the workbook is open to write a string into a cell within the range that is checked (I put the word "REPORT" in cell B1), which is, in effect, the first change to the sheet.

This occurs every time the book is opened and runs only once. Since it is at the top of the page and outside my table, it doesn't interfere with the data, but it solves the "first time into the loop" conundrum. It is effectively the first change to the array (Range(B:B)). After that, the "first" change (really the second!) is picked up and the counters are properly set.

Go freaking figure .......

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Make sure to accept your answer so that it shows up first on the list of answers.